# Read many videos and convert them into images

Tags: image, opencv, video

I have been able to get a program that can read a single video and convert it into images. However, actually, I am having many videos and I would like to write a function that can read the videos one by one and convert them into  images. I aim to convert the videos into images so as to facilitate the processing. The code for converting a single video is as follows.

```
import sys
import argparse

import cv2

vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('E:/DATA/1/12.mp4')
path_out = "E:/DATA_Synth/12" 

success,image = vidcap.read()
#image=cv2.resize(image, (640, 480))
count = 0
while success:
  cv2.imwrite(path_out + "/frame%03d.jpg" % count, image)    
  #cv2.imwrite(path_out + "/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)
  success,image = vidcap.read()
  #image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480))
  print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
  count += 1
```

Any suggestions and comments would be highly appreciated

Comment: Encapsulate your current code, which starts from `vidcap = ...` to `count+=1` inside a method say: `def get_frames(vid_file_path)` and then you iterate over all the video files like: `for vid_file_name in os.listdir("/your/local/directory")` and then call the `get_frames` inside this `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contributions. Please, could you give an illustration? I would like to save the frames differently with an indication referring to the corresponding video in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a loop to iterate through your folder which contains all your videos and pick each video and run your above code.

```
import os 
import sys
import argparse
import cv2
directory="enter your folder directory for video"
for vidfile in os.listdir(directory):
    if vidfile.endswith('.mp4'):
        vidcap=cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(directory, vidfile))
        ## write your code here for converting the video to individual frames
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Dear ShriKumaran, Than you very much for the reply. I have modified the codes as follows.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the codes as follows.

```
import os 
import sys
import argparse
import cv2
directory="E:/Training/video"
path_out = "E:/DATA_Synth/12" 
for vidfile in os.listdir(directory):
    if vidfile.endswith('.avi'):
        vidcap=cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(directory, vidfile))
        ## write your code here for converting the video to individual frames

        success,image = vidcap.read()
        #image=cv2.resize(image, (640, 480))
        count = 0
        while success:
            #vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC,(count*1000))
            cv2.imwrite(path_out + "/frame%03d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
            #cv2.imwrite(path_out + "/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)
            success,image = vidcap.read()
            #image = cv2.resize(image, (640, 480))
            #print ('Read a new frame: ', success)
            count += 1
    else:
        continue
```

However, only the frames from the last video in my directory are saved. Please, how can I modify the codes in such a way that the name of frame as written here

`cv2.imwrite(path_out + "/frame%d.jpg" % count, image)` 
may also contain the name of the corresponding video.